# How to pass pig option as parameter in oozie?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

In order to execute my pig script, i need to turn off optimizer. Using below command in command line and scripts work fine.

```
 pig -t ColumnMapKeyPrune population.pig
```

How to pass this option in oozie?

I tried passing as argument.

```
<action>
<pig>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>                      
    <script>Population.pig</script> 
    <argument>-t</argument>
    <argument>ColumnMapKeyPrune</argument>
    <param>piggybankJar=${piggybankJar}</param>
    <param>datafuJar=${datafuJar}</param>
    <param>inputPath=${inputPath}</param>
    <param>outputPath=${outputPath}</param>
</pig>
</action>
```

Received below error:

```
E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'param'. One of '{"uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":argument, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":file, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":archive}' is expected.
```

Tried using param, but it didnt worked

```
 <action>
 <pig>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>                      
    <script>Population.pig</script> 
    <param>-t</param>
    <param>ColumnMapKeyPrune</param>
    <param>piggybankJar=${piggybankJar}</param>
    <param>datafuJar=${datafuJar}</param>
    <param>inputPath=${inputPath}</param>
    <param>outputPath=${outputPath}</param>
</pig>
</action>
```

For pig oozie action allows only param, archive, file and argument tags. How to pass this optimizer_off option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the below mentioned property in your pig script and try once.

**set pig.optimizer.rules.disabled 'ColumnMapKeyPrune';**

for reference, please go through the below mentioned link

[http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/perf.html#optimization-rules]